# Call SpringBatch process from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-batch

I want to change the way we do things in a web application that has come into my hands.
The application uses Spring MVC, one of the screens of the application executes a process developed with SpringBatch on the server using the Runtime.exec(), similar to OS command (java -jar SpringBatchTask.jar ... etc.) I want to do is call the batch directly from the controller, without using the Runtime.exec. I have seen the Spring documentation for this, http://docs.spring.io/spring batch/reference/html/configureJob.html but I'm not clear as I have to set the context.xml of the web app and how to make the process to be recognized by the web application. Currently the process is well executed like this

```
process = rt.exec (prop.getProperty ("task") + "" + argumentString);
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: How are you planning on making the spring batch jar available to the web app (since I'm assuming it's sitting in a jar external to the web app)?

Comment: Yes Michael, Yes, it is an external jar. I'm not sure how to do, so posted the question. We work with Glassfish, I know level GlassFish Web application can use libraries (.jar's)
It could be one way. But you're absolutely right, somehow the jar of springbatch should be available to the application. Thanks!

Comment: So then are you planning on embedding the jar files into your WAR?  I can answer this either way but I need to know what your plans are for managing the jobs.

Comment: Hi! The job is simple, only read a .text file for an specific user and show the contain, no complex job planning. It´s only for start for something. Thanks! The jar file for springbatch will not be in the WAR, it will be in the GlassFish libs path if it´s possible, i don´t know, i have to make the test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch application are run by [`CommandLineJobRunner`](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiooqWdnd3RAhUBXBoKHaO4CjwQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.spring.io%2Fspring-boot%2Fdocs%2Fcurrent%2Fapi%2Forg%2Fspringframework%2Fboot%2FCommandLineRunner.html&usg=AFQjCNFrl9r-Ga69HltoqeqCFdP8WVIY9w), so the most easy way to call the job is directly calling the `main` method of this class:

```
CommandLineJobRunner.main(args);
```